# Can you have an if statement with in a class?

Tags: c#

hey i am relatively new to c sharp and coding and i am trying to create a class which i can call and print out later. The class i am trying to create contains a simple if statement such as if your car gives off so much emissions you pay a certain price. My problem is a cant quite be able to create an if in a class and then call it later. is this possible if not any help is much appreciated

```
 public double emissions;
 public double carTax;

 public double ifCarTax(double emissions)
        {
            carTax = if (emissions == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 120");
            }
            else if (emissions >= 1 && emissions <= 80)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 170");
            }
            else if (emissions >= 81 && emissions <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 180");
            }
            else if (emissions >= 101 && emissions <= 110)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 190");
            }
            else if (emissions >= 111 && emissions <= 120)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 200");
            }
            else if (emissions >= 121 && emissions <= 130)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 270");
            }
            else    //Catch invalid input
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid CO2 emissions");
            }

        }

        public double getCarTax()
        {
            return ifCarTax;
        }
```

Comment: show the code..

Comment: You need to first make a function in that class. That function will be callable and in it you can place your if statement

Comment: You will have to write a method in that class, the method may contain any valid C# code. You can later call the method from somewhere else.

Comment: Only in a constructor, a method or a property.

Comment: i posted the code there if it helps

Comment: @paul I'd suggest you work your way through a basic C# tutorial first - looks to me like you're trying to run when you can't yet crawl. There's plenty of good beginners tutorials available online.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic structure of a class...
If you post your actual code, we'll be able to tell you exactly where you went wrong.

```
using System;

class MyClassName
{
    static void YourMethodName(string incomingString1, string incomingString2)
    {
        if (1 == 1)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something different
        }
    }
}
```

Refactored your supplied code into this:

```
using System;

namespace _41002924
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CarTax.getCarTax(100));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class CarTax
    {
        public static double emissions { get; set; }
        public static double carTax { get { return getCarTax(emissions); } }

        public static double getCarTax(double emissions)
        {
            if (emissions == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 120");
                //carTax = 120;
                return 120;
            }
            else if (emissions >= 1 && emissions <= 80)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 170");
                //carTax = 170;
                return 170;
            }
            else if (emissions >= 81 && emissions <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 180");
                //carTax = 180;
                return 180;
            }
            else if (emissions >= 101 && emissions <= 110)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 190");
                //carTax = 190;
                return 190;
            }
            else if (emissions >= 111 && emissions <= 120)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 200");
                //carTax = 200;
                return 200;
            }
            else if (emissions >= 121 && emissions <= 130)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car tax is 270");
                //carTax = 270;
                return 270;
            }
            else    //Catch invalid input
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid CO2 emissions");
                //carTax = -999;
                return -999;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to post my code but its not coming out proper for me

Comment: @AnyoneDoing-1 Thanks for the -1 with no comment to back it up. Paul, I refactored your supplied code into something that will hopefully get you further.

Comment: I believe this solution has merit in clearing some of the confusion from the code supplied in the OP.

Comment: @blaze_125 i still dont understand how you are calling the class into the main programme why do you have 100 within the brackets

Comment: 100 is being passed in brackets because that is the value that is used to compute the answer. To _illustrate_ that, I am basically _~asking~_ : `hey CarTax` I have a question for you. My question is, `how much tax I need to pay if my emissions are 100?`. But that's the long form or asking... We know who to ask(`the class`), we know what to ask(`the method`) and we know what to ask against(`the parameter`) which yields something like this `CarTax.getCarTax(100)`

Comment: @nocturns2 thanks for understanding what I was trying to achieve in the first place. Clear a basic misconception of how code ties together. Just because we all once were noobies too!

Comment: @blaze_125 i have learned a different way on one thing and was just wondering if you could clear up the issue. The way i learned to set,get is like below: Can i just switch your method of get and setting to this and the code still should work correct ??  public void setYearOfManufacture(double newYearOfManufacture)
        {
            yearOfManufacture = newYearOfManufacture;
        }

        public double getYearOfManufacture()
        {
            return yearOfManufacture;
        }

Comment: In @blaze_125's static void Main(string[] args) method, the line: Console.WriteLine(CarTax.getCarTax(100)); would yield 180 to the console.

Comment: The public variables in my class can be commented out as they are not actually being used.

Comment: Suggestion: instead of several Console.WriteLines inside the `getCarTax`, do a single Console.WriteLine *after* the call, using the returned result.